# How to mix Oauth2 with JwtBearer in Swagger 5 and Asp Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, jwt, swagger

Here is my code adding swagger to service collection of asp core:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                var xmlDocPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Api.xml");

                options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlDocPath, true);


                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Version = "v1", Title = "Api V1 Docs"});


                options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    BearerFormat = "Bearer {Token}",
                    Name = "oauth2",
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Password = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            TokenUrl = new Uri("https://localhost:44362/api/Users/GenerateToken", UriKind.Absolute),
                        }
                    }                    
                });

                options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference {Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2"},
                        },
                        new string[] { }
                    } 
                });
             });
```

When I click to the authorize button in swagger and fill the credentials (username and pass) it get authorized but when I send a request to the server bearer token is ' undefined ' in header :

[image]

[image]

[image]

what is the problem ?
what should I do ?

Comment: Remove `BearerFormat`, `Name`, `Scheme` and `In` from `.AddSecurityDefinition(...)` (these parameters aren't used for OAuth 2 security schemes). Does this help?

Comment: @Helen  I did what you said, didn't fixed , but it also did not change any thing so they were extra.

Comment: How did you fix the bug?